# Circular Orbits Around a Reissner-Nordstrom Black Hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes

I'm doing some practice problems on GR and came across this which I'm totally stuck on:

The worldline of a photon orbiting a RN black hole is desribed by:

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{dr}{d\sigma}\right)^2 = k^2 - l^2 \frac{\alpha}{r^2} \\
\alpha = 1 - \frac{2GM}{r} + \frac{Q^2}{r^2}
\end{equation}

Where $k$ and $l$ are integration constants, $Q$ is the charge radius of the RN black hole $\sigma$ is an affine parameter. $r$ has its usual definition in spherical coordinates.

The question asks to find the value(s) of $r$ corresponding to circular orbits by differentiating equation 1 with respect to $\sigma$.

My knee jerk reaction to trying to find circular orbits would be to set the derivatives of $r$ to zero and solve for $r$ so I'm a bit stumped by the suggestion that I differentiate. I did try just to see where it went but I end up with a bunch of stuff that doesn't simplify to anything nice/anything I can interpret easily.

My questions are why does $\frac{dr}{d\sigma}=0$ not give you the solutions (or if it does, are there others?) and how to physically interpret $\frac{d}{d\sigma}\left( \frac{dr}{d\sigma}\right)^2$ so I might understand why I'm being asked to do that.

Comment: Can you give the text book reference?

Comment: A suggestion. Try first Schwarzschild case ($Q=0$). You'll have the same problem but mathematics is more manageable. So it could help you to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you have to solve both $dr/d\sigma =0$ and $d^2r/d\sigma^2=0$ at once. The reason for that is that if a ray reaches only $dr/d\sigma=0$ momentarily, this can be a *radial turning point* from which it still goes on to escape to infinity. Consider the following image ([source](https://www.realclearscience.com/blog/2015/07/can_light_orbit_massive_objects.html)):
[image]
Here you see the third ray from top approaching close to the black hole and then flying off. At the point it is closest to the black hole, it will obviously have $dr/d\sigma =0$ without being a circular orbit! So to make sure it is a circular orbit, you also have to make sure that the conditions are such that $d^2r/d\sigma^2=0$. Since the equations of motion of the light-ray are second order, this is really enough to make sure $r$ stays constant eternally.

Good luck!